# Windows 7 unable to detect a Windows Mobile device?

Tags: windows-7, activesync

I've spent the whole day trying to find solution and there are solutions, but they don't seem to work with my PC and device.

I just install Windows 7 and install Windows Mobile Device Center. Then I connect my device running under Windows Mobile 6, but it can not connect. I uncheck the "Enable advanced network functionality" through *Setting* -> *Connections* -> *USB to PC*, then restart the device and still it can not connect.

I uninstall WMDC, then restart my PC, and connect to device, but I still can not make a connection.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for responding. I just got it to work by following the instructions on 
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/help/synchronize/device-center-troubleshooting.mspx

While the device is connected, I uncheck the Enable advanced network functionality on the device (*Settings* -> *Connections* -> *USB to PC*), and then I uninstall any existing device driver under the Portable Devices node. *Start* -> *Control Panel* -> *Hardware and Sound* -> *Devices Manager*, *Portable Devices*. Disconnect the device and connect back-in, until Portable Devices node lists the actual connected device ID, and then install the Windows Mobile Device Center.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the link from MS Site on Troubleshooting this problem.  If it worked for you, then you may consider marking this question as "resolved"

Comment: I just  I unchecked the "Enable advanced network functionality" on the device (a CK3X in my case) and re-seated the device in its cradle and Win7 Mobile Device Center _finally_ connected to it.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the link doesn't work anymore :S

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows 7 64-bit machine, when I plugged in HTC Viva (USB), it couldn't detect the phone:

[image]

Later, I kept the phone connected (through USB) and manually went to Control Panel > Windows Update and clicked on Check for updates. After a few seconds, it detected the device and installed the appropriate driver.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Zune software from [Zune.net](http://www.zune.net). It's supposed to fix ActiveSync issues in Windows 7.

Comment: Is this some kind of publicity?